# Joomla, Proforms and conditional Paypal

Tags: php, joomla, paypal

I am rather new to Joomla, and have been asked to add a form with a PayPal option. So, the requirement is to redirect to PayPal on submission of the form **ONLY** if a checkbox is selected.

Is there a documented way of doing this with Proforms? I can't seem to find a way to do it. Also, I will need to change the cost of the purchase depending on a specific code the user will be entering in a field. Though, that bit will probably become obvious once the first requirement is satisfied.

I can easily do this hand coded, but Joomla is beyond me to be honest.

Comment: If you have the skills to make it hand coded, you just have to implement your code inside a [module](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module/Developing_a_Basic_Module).

Comment: @Emmanuel thank you very much for responding. I'll be sure to check this out tomorrow and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @emmanuel Thank you again for the response. However, I do not see how I would be able to connect a module to an existing ProForm. Remember, my requirement is to do this WITH Proforms, not in lieu of. Thank you again.

Comment: I have missed proforms part, I am not sure how it could be done.